# How to do Server Side PDF from Vue-Tables-2, Vue Js, and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pdf-generation, pdfmake, vue-tables-2

I have a `Vue-tables-2` datatable that I have a `createPDF()` method on a button - working as a client-side pdf generator using `pdfmake`

After review my client prefers to use a `server-side` pdf generator. I see that pdfmake has both client/server-side, but I am struggling to find examples that I can follow.

How can I either:

- Implement a server-side pdf using `pdfmake`
- Or switch to a package that is better for server-side pdf generation

Here is my client-side pdf code so far in my vue-tables-2 component:

```
<template>
    <el-container>
        <side-nav></side-nav>
        <el-main>
            <v-server-table url="/getListings" :data="tableData" :columns="columns" :options="options">
                <input slot="selected" slot-scope="props" type="checkbox" :checked="props.row.selected" v-model="checkedRows" :value="props.row">
                <button slot="afterFilter" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-pdf" @click="createPDF">Create Purchase Order</button>
            </v-server-table>
        </el-main>
    </el-container>
</template>


<script>

import {ServerTable, Event} from 'vue-tables-2';    
Vue.use(ServerTable, {}, false, 'bootstrap4');

var pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
    var pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            toggle:[],
            tableData: [],
            checkedRows: [],
            columns: [
                'selected',
                'sku',
            ],     
            options: {

            }
        }
    },

    methods: {

        createPDF() {
            var docDefinition = {
            content: [
                {
                    table: {
                        headerRows: 1,
                        widths: [ 'auto' ],

                        body: [
                            [{text: 'sku', bold: true}]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
            };
            for(var i=0;i<this.checkedRows.length;i++){
                docDefinition.content[0].table.body.push(Object.values(this.checkedRows[i]));  
            }
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('PO.pdf');
        }            
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: You will need something like [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) to run Vue as a server-sided application, which let's you execute your pdfmake-script on the server.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into Nuxt.js.